# Nucleo-STM32F429ZI Ethernet + LWIP (RAW API) - doesn't work

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, ethernet, lwip

I've got a project in which I have to communicate by Ethernet (TCP) Nucleo-STM32F429ZI with PC. STM32 will be sending the data from sensor periodically. I'm using STM32CubeIDE with built in CubeMX. I've connected the STM32 and the PC with a crossed cable. I configured it without RTOS, only using LwIP in RAW API mode with static IP addresses. I’m calling the MX_LWIP_Process() function in while loop.

My problem is that I can't receive ping response from STM32 and I’m getting the “Destination Host Unreachable” message. I've tried every configuration and advice I found on forums and it didn't work. I've tried to adapt my project configuration to that from the example for my board (LwIP_HTTP_Server_Netconn_RTOS which works and response) but it didn't work too.

As I'm debugging my project I can receive the ARP frame with request for IP address and I can see in debugger that the output frame is correct but as the whole payload is passed to "HAL_ETH_TransmitFrame" function, the output/response frame is gone, I can't see it in the Wireshark. I've checked the pinout configuration for the Ethernet peripheral and the configuration addresses. I really don't know what I’m missing.

I've got auto-negotiation enabled in ETH CubeMX and I've change the PHY address from default 1 to 0 and PHY Link down inturrupt from 0xB to 0x10 according to datasheet (I hope it's correct).

Below I pasted my configuration for Ethernet PHY (LAN8742A)

```
/* LAN8742A_PHY_ADDRESS Address*/

#define LAN8742A_PHY_ADDRESS           0U

/* PHY Reset delay these values are based on a 1 ms Systick interrupt*/

#define PHY_RESET_DELAY                 ((uint32_t)0x00000FFFU)

/* PHY Configuration delay */

#define PHY_CONFIG_DELAY                ((uint32_t)0x00000FFFU)



#define PHY_READ_TO                     ((uint32_t)0x0000FFFFU)

#define PHY_WRITE_TO                    ((uint32_t)0x0000FFFFU)



/* Section 3: Common PHY Registers */



#define PHY_BCR                         ((uint16_t)0x00U)    /*!< Transceiver Basic Control Register   */

#define PHY_BSR                         ((uint16_t)0x01U)    /*!< Transceiver Basic Status Register    */



#define PHY_RESET                       ((uint16_t)0x8000U)  /*!< PHY Reset */

#define PHY_LOOPBACK                    ((uint16_t)0x4000U)  /*!< Select loop-back mode */

#define PHY_FULLDUPLEX_100M             ((uint16_t)0x2100U)  /*!< Set the full-duplex mode at 100 Mb/s */

#define PHY_HALFDUPLEX_100M             ((uint16_t)0x2000U)  /*!< Set the half-duplex mode at 100 Mb/s */

#define PHY_FULLDUPLEX_10M              ((uint16_t)0x0100U)  /*!< Set the full-duplex mode at 10 Mb/s  */

#define PHY_HALFDUPLEX_10M              ((uint16_t)0x0000U)  /*!< Set the half-duplex mode at 10 Mb/s  */

#define PHY_AUTONEGOTIATION             ((uint16_t)0x1000U)  /*!< Enable auto-negotiation function     */

#define PHY_RESTART_AUTONEGOTIATION     ((uint16_t)0x0200U)  /*!< Restart auto-negotiation function    */

#define PHY_POWERDOWN                   ((uint16_t)0x0800U)  /*!< Select the power down mode           */

#define PHY_ISOLATE                     ((uint16_t)0x0400U)  /*!< Isolate PHY from MII                 */



#define PHY_AUTONEGO_COMPLETE           ((uint16_t)0x0020U)  /*!< Auto-Negotiation process completed   */

#define PHY_LINKED_STATUS               ((uint16_t)0x0004U)  /*!< Valid link established               */

#define PHY_JABBER_DETECTION            ((uint16_t)0x0002U)  /*!< Jabber condition detected            */



/* Section 4: Extended PHY Registers */

#define PHY_SR                          ((uint16_t)0x1FU)    /*!< PHY status register Offset                      */



#define PHY_SPEED_STATUS                ((uint16_t)0x0004U)  /*!< PHY Speed mask                                 */

#define PHY_DUPLEX_STATUS               ((uint16_t)0x0010U)  /*!< PHY Duplex mask                                 */



#define PHY_ISFR                        ((uint16_t)0x001DU)    /*!< PHY Interrupt Source Flag register Offset   */

#define PHY_ISFR_INT4                   ((uint16_t)0x0010U)  /*!< PHY Link down inturrupt       */
```

If you need any additional information about the setup please ask. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Just to be sure... it is the ARP reply that does not appear in wireshark, correct?  So you are having problems with ARP, not ICMP, and are using ping only because it triggers an ARP lookup?  If so, you should rewrite the sentence "My problem is that I can't receive ping response".

Comment: I can't receive reply on ARP request and therefore ICMP reply. So it's not like I have one problem with this but a few.

Comment: Just saying, that you never did send an ICMP ping, so everyone understands that having no ICMP reply is normal.  The fact that the ARP reply that you constructed never arrived at the PC is what is abnormal.

Comment: Do you have a serial port setup for debug tracing?  That would be a good first start, then you can trace if the interrupt handler is running, if the status bits from the PHY are ok, etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you for you answer. Ethernet RX mode is set in polling mode, so from the main loop I'm calling ethernetif_input() function which checks if some data arrived - it's the only way of checking if something came without RTOS. I've set breakpoints in whole project and I can trace the response payload on my ARP request, I've checked whole payload bit by bit and it's correct. I will check status register of the PHY as you said. I'm sorry but by the serial port setup for debug tracing you mean whether I set the output of debug messages to terminal? If that so I didn't but I will do it.

Comment: Once again, thank you for helping me.